# Splitting a ReportLab Flowable

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to write a Flowable for ReportLab, which needs to be able to split. Based on my understanding of the documentation, I need to define a function `split(self, aW, aH)` which splits the flowable up. I am, however, getting the following error which I cannot resolve.

A simple Flowable:

```
class MPGrid (Flowable):
def __init__(self, height=1*cm, width=None):
    self.height = height
    self.width = None

def wrap(self, aW, aH):
    self.width = aW
    return (aW, self.height)

def split(self, aW, aH):
    if aH >= self.height:
        return [self]
    else:
        return [MPGrid(aH, aW), MPGrid(self.height - aH, None)]

def draw(self):
    if not self.width:
        from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import LayoutError
        raise LayoutError('No Width Defined')

    c = self.canv
    c.saveState()
    c.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    c.restoreState()
```

When used in a document and requires splitting, produces the following error:

```
reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Splitting error(n==2) on page 4 in
<MPGrid at 0x102051c68 frame=col1>...
S[0]=<MPGrid at 0x102043ef0 frame=col1>...
```

This flowable should be a fixed height, and if it is too big for the available height, it is split to consume the height and then the reminder of the fixed height in the next frame.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this not-so-helpful error?

Answer (score 0):

With considerable more testing, I have come across an answer to this. I'm still open to better solutions if anyone has one.

This is happening because split is called twice, the second time when the available height is zero (or near zero) and you try create a flowable that has a (near) zero height. The solution is to check for this case and not be able to split in this case.

The revised code below has a few other minor changes as well, to make the code more "complete".

```
class MPGrid (Flowable):
def __init__(self, height=None, width=None):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width

def wrap(self, aW, aH):
    if not self.width:  self.width = aW
    if not self.height: self.height = aH

    return (self.width, self.height)

def split(self, aW, aH):
    if aH >= self.height:
        return [self]
    else:
        # if not aH == 0.0: (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485)
        if not abs(aH - 0.0) <= max(1e-09 * max(abs(aH), abs(0.0)), 0.0):
            return [MPGrid(aH), MPGrid(self.height - aH, None)]
        else:
            return []   # Flowable Not Splittable

def draw(self):
    if not self.width or not self.height:
        from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import LayoutError
        raise LayoutError('Invalid Dimensions')

    c = self.canv
    c.saveState()
    c.rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    c.restoreState()
```